# merging two lists in R (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: r, list, join, merge

I am trying to merge 2 lists in R. The names of the list should be used to perform the join. 
Here is a toy example:

```
> list1 <- list(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(2,4,5,6), C=c(1,3))
> list2 <- list(A=c(w,x), B=c(y,z))
```

The final merged list should look like this:

```
$w
[1] 1 2 3
$x
[1] 1 2 3
$y
[1] 2 4 5 6
$z
[1] 2 4 5 6
```

The only idea I had so far was to convert the lists to data frames, and use the merge function. Is there anything simpler to do?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: wait, what are `w`, `x`, `y` and `z`?  As you have it written there, the are the names of objects included in the list, not names of elements in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully this is something like what you want?  In fact you don't need `list2` at all.  Because lists are actually vectors, we can use a named vector to "lookup" the values of `list1` that we need, then assign those names to the new list

```
list1 <- list(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(2,4,5,6), C=c(1,3))

lookup <- c(w = "A",x = "A",y = "B",z = "B")

list2 <- list1[lookup]

names(list2) <- names(lookup)

list2
$w
[1] 1 2 3

$x
[1] 1 2 3

$y
[1] 2 4 5 6

$z
[1] 2 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This is a nice solution!